# How to traverse a matrix and make it fit these certain requirements?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a 4 x 3 matrix of 1's and -1's and would like rearrange the matrix so that there is a maximum of 2 positive one's per column. The two positive ones in the same column cannot be right above/below each other. They must be separated by at least one row.

Basically, I just want to make the matrix look like any of these [image: possibilities] where the black is -1 and white is 1.

I was thinking of printing out a list of all the column where the 1's are, and if any are next to each other, rearrange the list until it meets the requirements. Then, make another matrix that has the positive ones in the same columns as the numbers on the list. The rows would simply be 0, 1, 2, etc. Is there a way to rearrange lists easily in python? This is where I am mostly stuck.

Comment: What means "rearrange" here? Just arbitrarily set or swap entries in the matrix?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes exactly

Comment: Based on the requirements you wrote you could just count the number of 1s, create a new matrix with only -1s and set in the first row so many cells to 1 as there were 1s in the original matrix. If 1s are left over, continue with the third row.